# Java Web Error: Error : running Tomcat 7.0 : Cannot find configuration of jsp built-in servlet in

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, intellij-idea, web.xml

I,am trying to create my first project in Intellij idea 12  with Tomcat 8.0.0-RC5, OS Maverics , i use this tutorial :
http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_a_simple_Web_application_for_Tomcat_in_IntelliJ_IDEA_12

but when i do all steps i get error :

Error running Tomcat 7.0: Cannot find configuration of jsp built-in servlet in /Users/-------/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea12/tomcat/Unnamed_Simple_2/web.xml.

Answer (score 4):

Problem solved , Intellij don't suport tomcat 8

Answer (score 2):

Update your IntelliJ to atleast 12.1.5 or later (I updated mine to 12.1.6) and it'll work. Tomcat moved their web.xml into conf and IntelliJ had a bug that wasn't fixed until recently. [LINK](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-109063)

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking into using tomcat 8, try the EAP version, I'm running fine Idea with tomcat 8  http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+13+EAP